# Notepad++ Regex for append in begin of line Expression Part of Line

Tags: regex, notepad++

NotePad++ Regexp: I Would Want on a Line to Look for and to Isolate a Word and both Previous two words. The Word and to add them at the beginning of the Line

RegEx For Select In Line:

```
([a-zA-Z.,'*]+[ ])([a-zA-Z.,'*]+[ ])(Vs )([a-zA-Z.,'*]+[ ])([a-zA-Z.,'*]+[ ])
```

Would appreciate help on achieving this! Think

Exemple Lines Before:

```
- The Candidate o'Brien Vs O'Bama Presidential Test.
- traveling by plane Vs By TGV train.
- live stream info Chile vs Portugal How to watch Confederations Cup.
- band Cock Robin - Peter kingsbery Vs only the very best.
```

Lines After:

```
- Candidate o'Brien Vs O'Bama Presidential - Candidate o'Brien Vs O'Bama Presidential 
- by plane Vs Train TGV - traveling by plane Vs Train TGV French. 
- info Chile vs Portugal How - live stream info Chile vs Portugal How to watch Confederations Cup.
- Peter kingsbery Vs only the - band Cock Robin - Peter kingsbery Vs only the very best.
```

Nota :

When Append Firt Name Composite Ex: Jean-Claude The Line is Ignored.

- martial arts action Chuck Norris Vs Jean-Claude Van Damme and abbreviated as JCVD.

Answer (score 0):

I think you confused the output for the first and second lines, and the main problem is that you want to be able to match the whole string and *capture* the pattern you have provided to later be able to use the backreferences to both the whole line and Capturing group 1.

I suggest using

```
.*?((?:[a-zA-Z.,'*]+\h+){2}Vs(?:\h+[a-zA-Z.,'*]+){2}).*
```

and replace with `- $1 $0`.

The pattern is actually yours, I added `.*?` at the start and `.*` at the end (to match the whole line) and your pattern (with small enhancements) is put inside a capturing group `(...)` to be able to reference it later with `$1`. The `$0`  is the backreference to the whole match (here, the whole line).

**Pattern details**:

- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible (lazy match)
- `((?:[a-zA-Z.,'*]+\h+){2}Vs(?:\h+[a-zA-Z.,'*]+){2})` - Group 1 capturing:

  - `(?:[a-zA-Z.,'*]+\h+){2}` - exactly 2 occurrences of

    - `[a-zA-Z.,'*]+` - one or more ASCII letters, dots, `,`, `'`, or `*`
    - `\h+` - 1 or more horizontal whitespaces
  - `Vs`  - a `Vs`  substring
  - `(?:\h+[a-zA-Z.,'*]+){2}` - see above
- `.*`  -  any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible (greedy match)

[image]